# catch oracle sequence and set it to another field in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

An enity bean has generated sequence id (oracle primary key). We need to catch this sequence somehow on persist and set it to another field. For example:

```
class Entity {
    @Id long id;
    @Column long parentId;
}
```

The idea is to make parentId be the same as id generated by oracle if it is empty. For example:

```
@PrePersist
void prePersist() {
    if (parentId = 0) parentId = id; // but id is not yet generated
}
```

Currently we use DB trigger to achieve this, but can this be done in JPA (preferably without hibernate specific classes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we persist some `entity` in JPA, our `entity` object become managed, and at that point should have `id` populated. As its about pre-persist, not post-persist, you will not have your id populated.